# Insert/update database with text and image (varchar)

Tags: c#, sql-server, database, visual-studio

I am working with a database with 4 different columns `(id, surname, lastname and profilepicture)` and C# coding (Visual Studio).

The data type for the following are: `(id = int, surname = varchar, lastname = varchar, picture = varchar(MAX)`. 
I already inserted 3 rows with data, and I insert the pictures with link like this: `images/picture.jpg`

Now I want to insert new data with text-boxes and a picture-upload action.
I know I need to have an sqlCommand like this:

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("UPDATE studentreg SET id= '" + textBox1.Text +
    "',surname='" + textBox2.Text + "',lastname='" + textBox3.Text
```

But how do I get det "link" from an image uploader to be like the other I have? (like the same type!?)

This became very confusing, but hope you understand and may help me with the code for inserting these data?

Comment: Before you do anything else you need to read about, understand and start using parameterized queries. This is wide open to sql injection. My friend bobby tables loves applications like this. http://bobby-tables.com/

Answer (score 0):

assuming that you are using a web application and uploaded file will be saved to a folder called "images" (That's what I understood from your comment - insert the pictures with a link like this: images/picture.jpg. Please correct me if I'm wrong) You can use the function - FileUpload1.FileName to get the file name and then in the SQL statement use something like this

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("UPDATE studentreg SET id= '" + textBox1.Text + "',surname='" + textBox2.Text + "',lastname='" + textBox3.Text+"',picture = 'images/"+FileUpload1.FileName+"'";
```